# Libgdx - how to get absolute path to working directory?

Tags: libgdx

I am aware this is a strange request, seeing as LibGDX does a excellent job of abstracting away file system differences with functions like;

```
file = Gdx.files.internal(location);
```

Which is exactly what I use to retrieve files.

However I have a situation where knowing the actual absolute path to what that "internal" directory is would be highly useful.
What would be a good approach to get it?

Would I need to write a per-platform method then somehow selectively call them based on what implementation is running? 
For example in gwt I could use;

```
GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()
```

Or is there a more sensible approach making use of GDX functions to get the absolute path to the working directory?

*update*

Ok, given that its apparently impossible on Android to get a full path, it looks like I will need a platform specific solution ignoring Android, and will need to work out myself some other work-around for android.

So how would I approach this? Some way to run code-per-platform that returns working directory's for those platforms that can?

Thanks,

### darkflame

*For those curious as to why Id want this path;*

My project involves extensive use of semantic data. Semantic nodes require a URI - a unique way to identify a resource. For example DBPedias apple is "http://dbpedia.org/resource/apple" where "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" is the uri. For local filesystems rather then online, it makes sense to use the directory to uniquely identify elements.
So while the URI path to the information should be correct its not really a file-retrieval issue so much as about supplying a unique identity.

(it would take *a lot* of explanation to go into full detail here, so please don't suggest workarounds to the need for this path. I have my own in mind if its impossible, but it gets fairly complex so id rather not)

Comment: Note the only reason LibGDX abstracts away file paths is that Android does. It is impossible to get an absolute path to a file in Android.

Comment: ah. hmm....arr... *thinks*

Comment: FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath()